# PHP adds keys to decoded and then encoded JSON data

Tags: php, json

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I seem to run into this problem often. Here is my original JSON for a shopping cart:

```
{
    "cartitems": [
        {
            "Product_ID": "1",
            "quantity": "1",
            "cartid": 1
        },
        {
            "Product_ID": "5",
            "quantity": "1",
            "cartid": 4
        },
        {
            "Product_ID": "5",
            "quantity": "1",
            "cartid": 6
        },
        {
            "Product_ID": "5",
            "quantity": "1",
            "cartid": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

This JSON data is stored to the $_SESSION variable, $_SESSION['cart_items']

This code is used to remove an item:

```
$cartid = $_POST['varA'];

/* Remove the item */
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_items']['cartitems'] as $key => $product) {
    if ($product['cartid'] == $cartid) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_items']['cartitems'][$key]);
    }
}


echo json_encode($_SESSION['cart_items']);
```

When the item with cartid = 7 is removed, the result is this when it is endoded:

```
{
    "cartitems": {
        "0": {
            "Product_ID": "1",
            "quantity": "1",
            "cartid": 1
        },
        "1": {
            "Product_ID": "5",
            "quantity": "1",
            "cartid": 4
        },
        "2": {
            "Product_ID": "5",
            "quantity": "1",
            "cartid": 6
        }
    }
}
```

It adds keys! This only occurs when there are more than 3 items, which baffles me. Is there any way I can re-write my code so that it prevents theses keys from being created?

Comment: http://codepad.org/NXLF00eg - cannot reproduce

Comment: I think @jack's code is the answer..as he does a `json_decode` before doing a `foreach`.

Comment: Btw, did you make sure to also do an `echo json_encode($_SESSION['cart_items']);` *before* modifying the array?

Comment: I apologize. The data is not JSON data, I just wrote its JSON equivalent. It is a PHP array

Comment: And I see that example on codepad. I am not sure why it is behaving like this. I think deceze knows why below

Comment: @TaylorMac it helps to `var_dump()` your session to find out what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, there are only arrays, which are used for both associative and numerically indexed maps/lists/arrays. Javascript/JSON has two distinct concepts: numerically indexed arrays (`[...]`) and object maps (`{ foo : ... }`). For PHP's `json_encode` to decide which to use when encoding an array, there's some logic behind the scenes. Generally, if the array keys are contiguous and all numerical, the array is encoded to a JSON array (`[...]`). If there's even one key out of order or a non-numeric key, a JSON object is used instead.

Why your array manipulation in particular triggers an object, I don't know. To avoid this though, you can reset your array keys to make sure they're numerically, contiguously indexed:

```
$_SESSION['cart_items']['cartitems'] = array_values($_SESSION['cart_items']['cartitems']);
```

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense. However when I reset the array as you have put it, I get this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: OK. my bad it doesn't give that error. However, it doesn't seem to fix the issue. I'm sure this is the correct method, I just do not know why it's still in as an object after manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me.
Transfer the array to a new array with auto keys:

```
/* Remove the item */
foreach ($_SESSION['cart_items']['cartitems'] as $key => $product) {
    if ($product['cartid'] == $cartid) {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_items']['cartitems'][$key]);
    }
}
$var=array();
foreach($_SESSION['cart_items']['cartitems'] as $key => $product) {
        $var['cart_items']['cartitems'][] = $product;
}
echo json_encode($var['cart_items']);
```